# Angular resource query param appended in overriden action URL

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-resource, angular-routing

This is my resource configuration as you can see I'm overriding url in add action.

```
var CommerceService = ['$resource', 'context', function ($resource, context) {
    return $resource('api/commerces/:id', {id: 0}, {
        add: {url: 'api/commerces/new/storesNumber/:storesNumber', method: 'POST', params: {storesNumber: 0}},
        findMallStores: {url: 'api/commerces/mall/:id/stores', method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    });
}];
```

This is how I call that particular action

```
//more code
var stores = 0;
commerce.$add({storesNumber: stores}).then(function (response) {
   $location.path('/commerces/show/' + response.id);
});
```

This is the result that I'm getting.

`http://localhost:8080/commerce-web/api/commerces/new/storesNumber/0?id=0`

I'm expecting to get a URL like this

`http://localhost:8080/commerce-web/api/commerces/new/storesNumber/0`

This still works, but I'm expect not to get de query param 'id' appended in the URL.
 
What am I doing wrong? And more important Why is this happening?

Comment: the specified route controller must be doing something like adding `$location.search('id', 0)`

Comment: I think maybe something like that was happening. I solved passing an empty argument to that parameter in the resource action, like explained below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, basically the trick to strip the base URL expected parameter was passing an empty object as an argument -> `{id: undefined}`

```
//more code
var stores = 0;
commerce.$add({id: undefined, storesNumber: stores}).then(function (response) {
   $location.path('/commerces/show/' + response.id);
});
```

now the URL is as expected without the base URL resource parameter.